# "I cut it by hand" - what is "by hand"? (Grammatically)

Tags: prepositional-phrases, modifiers, adjuncts

> I cut it **by hand**.

Does it (vaguely) make sense to call it a transitive verb?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*By hand* is not any kind of verb.<sup>†</sup> It's an ordinary preposition phrase modifying the verb phrase *cut it*, describing the manner or means of cutting.

Because it modifies a verb phrase in the same way as an adverb like *manually*, many traditional grammarians would call this use of the phrase an "adverb phrase", because traditional grammar names the syntactic role a phrase after the part-of-speech which typically plays that role. We're pickier today—we reserve the term "adverb phrase" for phrases headed by an actual adverb—but some of us might call the phrase an "adverbial".

<sup>†</sup> <sub>Don't be misled by that *by*; in this case *by* doesn't serve to designate the Agent of a passive-voice verb.</sub>

Comment: That's what I thought too - but in one of the IOL papers the question put "by hand" and "by tool" under transitive verbs so I was confused and a bit suspicious. Thank you for the detailed answer!

Comment: Interesting. My mother, who was an English professor, used the terms "adjectival phrase" and "adverbial phrase" when explaining them to me when I was a boy in the 60's.

Comment: @BobRodes That is mystifying. How could a phrase headed by the preposition _by_ be any but a preposition phrase?

Comment: @P.E.Dant It's a preposition phrase employed as an adverbial is how.

Comment: @BobRodes Indeed. My father (also an Eh prof) was likewise careful to distinguish the internal structure and the external syntactic function.

Comment: @StoneyB But even if you dress the preposition phrase up in a tiny silk top hat and a tiny black cutaway, and provide it with tiny white gloves and a minute leather portfolio, and send it to represent you at an international gathering of top ministers, it does not become a diplomat: it is still a preposition phrase _serving as_ a diplomat.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Well, a preposition phrase would do a better job than some of our political appointees . . .